# Easy way to match a string with keywords in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I allow users to put keywords and, if someone create a project with these keywords, the user receive email alert.

But I have a problem and, I think, I need regex, but I don't know how.
If a user puts, for example, "UX" in keywords, he will receive email when someone creates a project with a word like "veUX" (in french).

I need to check, in Ruby, if the keyword in the string is a word (with whitespace before and after, for example) and not characters in word.

Do you know how can I do it?

This is my job :

```
  def common_keywords_email_alert?(user, project)
    name_description = I18n.transliterate([project.name.downcase, project.description.downcase].join(' '))
    user.email_alert.keywords&.any? do |keyword|
      user.email_alert.keywords.join(' ')
      name_description.include?(keyword)
    end
  end
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the boundary directive, \b (https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
regex = /\bUX\b/
"blah".match(regex) # => nil
"veUX".match(regex) # nil
"my UX".match(regex) # => #<MatchData "UX">
"UX".match(regex) # => #<MatchData "UX">
"UX is great".match(regex) # => #<MatchData "UX">
```